# Analog of perfectly matched layers for finite element methods

Tags: finite-element

Is there an analog of perfectly matched layers for finite element methods? References or small examples are much appreciated.

Comment: I have seen plenty of papers with PML for FEM. E.g., http://ftp.lstc.com/anonymous/outgoing/ubasu/website/papers/basu-fdpml.pdf

Comment: That's great for wave equations, but what about something like a Poisson equation? Any good references?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A perfectly matched layer (PML) is generally introduced as a continuous concept without reference to the discretization method. A damping term is multiplied by the advection operator:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \rightarrow \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{1}{1 + i\sigma/\omega}\right)
$$
If $\sigma$ is positive, the imaginary component in the above equation drives the standard oscillatory solution of a wave equation to be exponentially decaying. A simple way of implementing this would just modify the discretized equation everywhere in space and then assign the value of $\sigma$ to be zero everywhere except near the boundaries.

So, a PML could be implemented in any volumetric discretization like finite volumes, finite elements or finite differences.

For an introduction, I like these [notes](http://math.mit.edu/~stevenj/18.369/pml.pdf). Also, try this [paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=504304).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at some of the papers by my colleague Joe Pasciak on the PML and its approximation: http://www.math.tamu.edu/~joe.pasciak/